# Customizing quick create form

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016

I'm trying to customize this form (making 'Description' optional when 'Left voice mail' is selected) and I can't find the form associated with what I'm seeing here:

[image]

I've tried copying the default, managed Quick View form for Phone Call and reordering the copy before the default managed one and clicking "Add Phone Call" is never showing my form.

Is this pop up form even customizable ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a Quick Create Form. It is a part of the Social Pane, which cannot really be customized.

Instead of the Social Pane, you use a normal subgrid of activities instead. In this way you will get the normal Quick Create Form when adding new activities.